# How can I to restrict the execution of an imacros script between some hours?

Tags: windows-10, imacros

I have an imaros script that runs each 4 minutes (using auto clicker)... but I need to it doesn't run between 23:30 to 00:30... so I need to do something like:

If (date is <23:30 and date is > 00:30) then run!!

Is this possible?

many thanks!

Comment: CIM...! => Read my Sig/Profile and/or open a parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum... - But, yep, of course "it's possible"...! - And correct Spelling is "iMacros", you'll have to spell it correctly for me to help you...

Comment: + Don't know what your "auto clicker" is...? => Care to explain...? - What have you tried...? (Post your Script...)

Comment: autoClicker is an app that that you can set to click somewhere in the screen each X sencod you want. So I have autoclicker running and it click on the PLAY button of iMacros each 4 minutes... say and night, so I need to mi script does run just between 00:30 and 23:30

Comment: Sorry... THANKS for your helping hand!

Comment: Yeah, you're welcome, but you would get a better "Help" if you mentioned your FCI (Full Config Info)... - Hum, that 'autoClicker' sounds interesting, no Link provided, I''ll wait for your FCI to check if I can use it...

Comment: Yep, found it I think: 'AutoClicker' v1.0.0.2 (but says "v3.0" when running it): https://sourceforge.net/projects/orphamielautoclicker/files/latest/download - A bit buggy, but it works, and it even works on Multiple Screens (x3), very good...!

Comment: + Parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum (opened by me): https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=30415

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with JavaScript. You can create current time in JS and compare it with time between the two times you named. It's a little complicated to make. Msg me on private messages and we can work things out.

Comment: Thanks, but I have to change the solution... it is not posible to do it as ipswitch team told me... :(

Comment: I don't see the problem. I can write this code in JavaScript and show you. Just msg me on private

Comment: Hum, checking this Thread a few weeks later and I don't know where you got that "it is not posible to do it as ipswitch team told me..." from, I can't find any parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum, and this "Statement" is a bit nonsense... - Functionality is pretty straightforward to implement, either in '.js' like 'macroscript' suggests, but also in pure '.iim', there are several possible Implementations..., and none are very difficult...

Comment: @chivracq how to do it in iim?

Comment: @macroscripts (Oh..., sorry for late Reply, but I had stopped checking this Thread...) => With a "Conditional 'WAIT'" for example, or with 'EVAL()' + 'MacroError()' to abort the Macro, or by conditionally toggling '!ERRORIGNORE' on some "fake" Element, I can probably find half a dozen of possible Implementations.. (All in pure '.iim'...)

Comment: + With a "Conditional/Deliberate 'FAIL_IF_FOUND' also... All 4 with a check on '!NOW' or a JS 'Date()' Object => + Using OS Task Scheduler. Can relaunch the Macro using 'URL GOTO' or embedded Macro in a Local Page (2 ways), 4 ways if embedded in a Link or Button... => Tot =17 different ways now, hum +1 from a '.js' Script to launch a '.BAT' File (=> +2 as the check can also be done on '!NOW' of 'Date()'), same 'BAT' File can also be launched from the 'EVENT' Mode (+ 'External Application Buttons' Add-on FF) (=> +2) => Total = 21 different ways now..., oh hum!, "only" 19 as 2 were with '.js'.

Comment: Hum, +2 by launching their Auto-Click App from the OS Task Scheduler, either from a specific Time and Nb of Repeats carefully calculated until Stop-Time, or by also launching at Stop-Time another '.BAT' that will kill the Process of that App. Tot=21...! Oh..., or the Browser, ah-ah...! Tot=22...!

Comment: +2 by launching just before Stop-Time another "fake" Macro that won't do anything..., except relaunching the "good" Macro again at Start-Time... Tot=24. +2 on the first/real 'URL GOTO' in the Macro can be Conditional to go to some "fake" URL where it won't do anything... Tot=26...

Comment: Hum..., a bit "afraid" @OP will delete their Thread (which happens with more than 50% of 'iMacros' Threads from 1st time Poster on SOF), and i find it quite interesting after all, and a bit funny of course, I've opened a parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum, where hopefully a few other Advanced Users (+ TechSup) will react...: https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=30415